# ANTLR4 Beta 3 Very simple grammar not working

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Here is a very simple grammar:

```
grammar test;

DIGIT : [0-9] ;
WS : [ \r\n\t]+ -> skip ;
value : DIGIT+ ;
```

Using antlr v4.0b3 under OSX and JAVA version 1.6

Compiling the grammar with the following commands:

```
antlr4 test.g4
javac *.java
```

I then used grun to test the grammar:

```
grun test value -tokens
```

And here is the result:

```
grun test value -tokens
12
[eof]
[@0,0:0='1',<1>,1:0]
[@1,1:1='2',<1>,1:1]
[@2,3:2='<EOF>',<-1>,2:0]
```

My question is: why do I get two tokens ('1' and '2') instead of one ('12')?

Thanks a lot for those who can help me!!

Cheers!

Guy

Answer (score 4):

You have asked DIGIT to match a single digit at a time, which are then passed to the parser rule: value. I think what you want is really

```
value : INT ;
INT : [0-9]+ ;
```

:)

Terence

Comment: Hi Terrence. Thanks a lot! I've just found the same answer by myself... I've been puzzled for the last 2 hours by that stupid mistake!